# Laravel Controller Layout testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, controller, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to include unit-testing in a new Laravel app I'm building.
Right now I'm want to test my OrderController. The index method of this controller looks like this:

```
public function index()
{
    // We need the extra 'orders()' for the query scope
    $orders = $this->order->orders()->paginate($this->perPage);

    $this->layout->content = View::make('orders.index', compact('orders'));
}
```

Now I have my test that looks like this:

```
public function testIndex()
{
    $this->call('GET', 'orders');

    $this->assertResponseOk();

    $this->assertViewHas('orders');
}
```

Now if I run phpunit, the test does run, but I'm getting: `1) OrderControllerTest::testIndex
Failed asserting that an array has the key 'orders'.`

I've tracked down the issue to using Controller Layouts `$this->layout`. 
If I just do `return View::make()` the test does pass, if I return `$this->layout...` it also does pass, but this destroys the actual app.

So only option I've found is to use `return View::make()` and have `@extends('master')` in that view. But it's seems strange to me that you can't use Controller Layouts in your app if you want to test it.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The reason the test fails is because the Orders.Index view is rendered into the layout, so by the time you test, the orders variable has already been rendered and no longer exists. I'm not sure what the best approach to test is though... You could check that the orders.index view contains the orders variable in a separate test and then check that the combined view contained a 'content' variable but that's all I can think of.

Answer (score 9):

**Edit:**
I had the same problem and here is slightly messy solution that works!

```
    View::composer('ordersviewname', function($view) {
      $this->assertArrayHasKey('orders', $view->getData());
    });

    $this->call('GET', 'orders');
```

Note that you have to put this code BEFORE `$this->call()`

**EDIT:**
Here is more elegant solution!
Add  functions to TestCase

```
    protected $nestedViewData = array();

    public function registerNestedView($view)
    {
      View::composer($view, function($view){
        $this->nestedViewsData[$view->getName()] = $view->getData();
      }); 
    }

    /**
     * Assert that the given view has a given piece of bound data.
     *
     * @param  string|array  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function assertNestedViewHas($view, $key, $value = null)
    {
        if (is_array($key)) return $this->assertNestedViewHasAll($view, $key);

        if ( ! isset($this->nestedViewsData[$view]))
        {
            return $this->assertTrue(false, 'The view was not called.');
        }

        $data = $this->nestedViewsData[$view];

        if (is_null($value))
        {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $data);
        }
        else
        {
            if(isset($data[$key]))
              $this->assertEquals($value, $data[$key]);
            else 
              return $this->assertTrue(false, 'The View has no bound data with this key.');            
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assert that the view has a given list of bound data.
     *
     * @param  array  $bindings
     * @return void
     */
    public function assertNestedViewHasAll($view, array $bindings)
    {
        foreach ($bindings as $key => $value)
        {
            if (is_int($key))
            {
                $this->assertNestedViewHas($view, $value);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->assertNestedViewHas($view, $key, $value);
            }
        }
    }

    public function assertNestedView($view)
    {
      $this->assertArrayHasKey($view, $this->nestedViewsData);
    }
```

Now you would rewrite your test

```
$view='orders';
$this->registerNestedView($view);

$this->call('GET', 'orders');

$this->assertNestedViewHas($view, 'orders');
```

`assertNestedViewHas()` has all the same feautures as `assertViewHas()` !

I added another function `assertNestedView()` which just check if given view was called.

Comment: +1 - This is a great solution which makes templating TDD possible now. You should consider putting this forward as a suggestion for Laravel 4.1

Comment: Very elegant solution. I would definitely consider adding a suggestion for laravel 4.1